# Trying to make a marquee

Tags: javascript, animation, marquee

I am currently generating the elements putting them into a container and I want that container to move from right to left of the marquee tag.

HTML:

```
    <div class="news_wrapper">
        <div class="news_start"></div>
        <div class="news_end"></div>
        <div id="marquee" class="news_text">
            <!--<p>Consider a small donation btc: 114t1q7Fro4JCANagYMF55BynAGhvsk39z</p>-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function createElement(type, attributes, someElement) {
    var element = document.createElement(type);
    for (var key in attributes) {
        if (key === "class") {
            var cls = attributes[key];
            for (var c in cls)
                element.classList.add(cls[c]);
        } else {
            element[key] = attributes[key];
        }
    }
    someElement.appendChild(element);
}

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var news_marquee = document.getElementById("marquee"),
                    news_marquee_width,
                    news_volatility,
                    news_class,
                    news_name,
                    news_track,
                    news_track_width,
                    lcal_coinsss,
                    find_volatility;

            add_news();

            function move_news() {
                news_track_width = news_track_width + 1;
                console.log(news_track_width);
                news_track.style.right = "-" + news_track_width + "px";
                setInterval(move_news, 1000);
            }

            function add_news() {
                lcal_coinsss = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coinss'));
                find_volatility = findVolatility(lcal_coinsss);

                var newElement = createElement("div", {
                    "id": "news_track",
                    "class": ["news_track"]
                }, news_marquee);
                news_track = document.getElementById("news_track");

                for (var i in find_volatility) {
                    news_volatility = find_volatility[i][1];
                    if (news_volatility >= 1) {
                        news_class = "positive_number_text";
                    } else if (news_volatility <= -1) {
                        news_class = "negative_number_text";
                    }

                    var newElement = createElement("p", {
                        "id": "news_name" + find_volatility[i][0],
                        "class": ["news_name"]
                    }, news_track);
                    news_name = document.getElementById("news_name" + find_volatility[i][0]);
                    news_name.textContent = find_volatility[i][0];

                    var newElement = createElement("span", {
                        "id": "news_volatility" + find_volatility[i][0],
                        "class": [news_class]
                    }, news_track);
                    news_volatility = document.getElementById("news_volatility" + find_volatility[i][0]);
                    news_volatility.textContent = find_volatility[i][1];
                }
                news_marquee_width = news_marquee.offsetWidth;
                news_track_width = news_track.offsetWidth;
                news_track.style.right = "-" + news_track_width + "px";
                move_news();
//                    console.log(news_marquee_width);
//                    console.log(news_track_width);
                }
```

I am generating the elements, and they are in a wrapper inside the marquee but I am not able to move it as I want to, when I run the `move_news` it will add right CSS expotentional.

Basically I want the generated `div` with content to move in a marquee style.
If anyone has any suggestions towards the whole script please let me know.

Comment: I think this might be better suited to a CSS animation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: Im not sure about this, but i will give css animations a go.. i still dont understand why my pixels are expotential, 2-4-8-16....

Comment: There's a good example of how to achieve it here: https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/kfmKa